# Error on javascript queryselector

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to input an URL Parameter into a form input. When I'm trying to do it via the inspect console, everything seems fine. But when I load the page I got an error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null.

Here the main javascript

```
function getParameterByName(name)
 {
  name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\\]");
  var regexS = "[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)";
  var regex = new RegExp(regexS);
  var results = regex.exec(window.location.href);
  if(results == null)
     return "";
  else
 return decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
 }
```

my input looks like this... There is a part of the ID that randomly changes on reload, only satisfaction_case_number stay the same.

```
<input id="satisfaction_case_number-da4e00e8-dcf6-4efa-9f92-d9564432f979_2621" class="hs-input" type="text" name="satisfaction_case_number" value="" placeholder="" data-reactid=".hbspt-forms-0.0:$0.$satisfaction_case_number.0">
```

I tried 2 functions call.

```
document.getElementByName("satisfaction_case_number").value = getParameterByName("case")
```

and

```
document.querySelector('[id^="satisfaction_case_number"]').value = getParameterByName("case")
```

I have to say I'm kinda blind here. Any flag would be appreciated.

Here is the URL of my page : http://info.techo-bloc.com/customer-service-0?case=CAS-00745-Z0G5F8.

I'm trying to get : CAS-00745-Z0G5F8 into the input.
Thanks

Comment: Are you using jQuery really? or added by mistake to the OP ?

Comment: There is no `getElementByName`, there's a `getElementsByName` that returns a collection. `document.querySelector('[id^="satisfaction_case_number"]').value = "foo"` worked fine for me on your page.

Comment: [querySelector](https://jsfiddle.net/ewh73how/1/) works fine.

Comment: If you mean you can't get the right *value* into the element then there's something wrong with your `getParameterByName` code.

Comment: Is the HTML there when the page loads, or is it added dynamically? That might be an issue.

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki, this isn't about getting params. That duplicate question wasn't going to help.

Comment: Its.. just passing the param as argument instead will do the job.

Comment: @Dave Newton If i inspect the element and put : document.querySelector('[id^="satisfaction_case_number"]').value = getParameterByName("case") into the console i got the right value. But onload of the page i got the error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null.

Comment: @Andy I'm not sure... it's being done by hubspot as a form.. so maybe the form comes after the page has load... If this is the case.. i should do a window.setTimeout ?

Answer (score 1):

Wait till the window has loaded then execute it;

```
window.onload = function () {
    document.getElementsByName("satisfaction_case_number")[0].value = getParameterByName('case'); 
}
```

The form is being dynamically generated after the rest of your content has loaded, It's unreliable to rely on timing as connection speeds can vary, using 
 `window.onload` will ensure the page is fully loaded before executing.

I tested this by throttling my browser connection to "Slow 3G" and it still worked, Your original piece of code that selected the element by name wasn't selecting the first entry in the NodeList, to do this you need to add `[0]` before the `.value`

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded may work also (it's earlier)

Answer (score 0):

You can try `document.querySelector('input[id *= satisfaction_case_number]').value = 'example'`

Answer (score -1):

```
setTimeout(function () {
  var input = document.querySelector('[id^="satisfaction_case_number"]');
  input.value = getParameterByName('case');
  input.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
}, 1000);
```

or try to modify the code that creates HubSpot form:

```
hbspt.forms.create({
  // ...
  onFormReady: function () {
    var input = document.querySelector('[id^="satisfaction_case_number"]');
    input.value = getParameterByName('case');
    input.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
  }
});
```

Comment: This isn't the issue. See the comments below the question.

Comment: Maybe the element doesn't exists in the moment you are trying to access it?

Comment: I've update the answer, please try these solutions. Likely that the element you are updating doesn't exist at the very beginning. So you need to wait for them moment when it appears. Probably the library that renders the form provides a hook for it (something like `onReady` or similar?).

Comment: @DmitryDruganov It worked with a timeout... guess the form wasn't loaded at the beginning. The addEventListener didn't work tho...

Comment: I see that you are using HubSpot API to create the form. I'm not familiar with it, but looks like it provides `onFormReady` hook. Try it also.

Comment: @DmitryDruganov I added the code and it worked, but when I click on the other input it disappears... any idea why?

Comment: Try `document.querySelector('[id^="satisfaction_case_number"]').blur()` right after the value assignment

Comment: When you modify the value you also need to notify the form about the change. Triggering of `blur` does the trick. Also take a look to [HubSpot API docs](https://developers.hubspot.com/docs/methods/forms/advanced_form_options). Likely that there should be a way to provide initial values for the form.

Comment: Im not familar enough with API to go that way.. 
should it look like this ?
setTimeout(function () {
 document.querySelector('[id^="satisfaction_case_number"]').value = getParameterByName("case");
  
}, 1000);
document.querySelector('[id^="satisfaction_case_number"]').blur();

Comment: You need to add the last line to the setTimeout callback. Also try the updated solution

Comment: @DmitryDruganov added the script on the website, but still the same... is it possible HubSpot has events handler on inputs? and that's why I keep clearing it?

Comment: @AntoineSp Try with `dispatchEvent` (see updated code)

Comment: @AntoineSp Did you have a chance to try the solution with `dispatchEvent`?

Comment: Somebody who've just downvoted the answer, could you please clarify it?

Comment: @DmitryDruganov no, actually I found out that HubSpot will automatically paste the value if the parameter is the same as his internal key! So didn't have to to use java :) Thanks tho for your help :)